# Responsive design / scaling modules according to resolution

Tags: css, joomla

I added the following module to joomla "Left right image slideshow" this can be found at http://www.gopiplus.com/extensions/2011/07/left-right-image-slideshow-joomla-module/#comments
in this module the available customize settings is the following:

Width (px):  |***_*__**| <----textbox
Height (px):  |**__*_*_**| <----textbox

This works fine the only problem is that if I open it on another computer with a different screen resolution the imageview is too big or too small. After doing some research I found that I need to use "%" instead of px, but in this case as you can see in the picture the textbox is only for px. In this case how can I change my imageview to adjust when the resolution changes?

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hardcoded to be *px* in the file `/modules/mod_left_right_image_slideshow/tmpl/left-right-image-slideshow-gallery.js`.
The best solution would probably be to contact the developer of the module and suggest him supporting your wish. Or just use a different module from the huge list of available slideshow modules: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow.